# How to randomly select elements with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

is there any option in jquery to randomly select number`(3)` of elements with in the same class name ?

Actually I just wanna slideup up **3 items** only which should be **randomly**

```
function e(e) {
    var t = $(window).scrollTop(),
        n = t + $(window).height(),
        r = $(e).offset().top,
        i = r + $(e).height() * .8;
    return i >= t && r <= n && i <= n && r >= t
}

function s() {
    if (e(t) && !i) {
        r.each(function (e) {
            $(this).delay(200 + e * 50).animate({
                top: "-110%"
            }, 500)
        }).each(function (e) {
            $(this).delay(200 + e * 100).animate({
                top: "0%"
            }, 500)
        });
        i = !0
    }
    i && $(window).unbind("scroll", s)
}
var n = $("#thumbs"),
    t = $(".thumbnails"),
    r = n.find(".thumb-info"),
    i = !1;
s();
$(window).bind("scroll", s);
```

**DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/GgY3Z/**

Comment: use Math.rand to get a random seed and use it to select your elements(based on their index for example)

Comment: implement `Math.floor((Math.random()*r.length)+1);`

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee `Math.rand` doesn't exist. You probably mean `Math.random()` which returns a decimal between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Broxzier yes that's what I meant. And you can multiply it by your max to get a random number. Math.random()*3 to get 0,1,2

Comment: Could you please use shorter names for your functions and vars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var items = $('.thumbnails');
var random = shuffle(items).slice(0, 3);
```

Explanation:

1. `$('.thumbnails')` selects all elements with class `thumbnails`
2. [`shuffle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript) returns 3 random elements from the array (check out the link)
3. `.slice(0, 3)` grabs the first 3 values of the shuffled array.

Here's a Fiddle I made to see the result: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGxVR/)</kbd>

Comment: I'm not seeing a lot of randomness in your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shuffle algorithm, for example

```
function shuffleArray(a) { // Fisher-Yates shuffle, no side effects
    var i = a.length, t, j;
    a = a.slice();
    while (--i) t = a[i], a[i] = a[j = ~~(Math.random() * (i+1))], a[j] = t;
    return a;
}
```

Shuffle your *Array* of elements;

```
myArray = shuffleArray(myArray);
```

Now the first `3` items are random, so loop over them with your slide.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 3 && i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    // slide myArray[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is pure js and does that what you need

```
var fys=function(d,a,b,c){ //FisherYatesShuffle
 a=d.length;
 while(--a){
  b=Math.floor(Math.random()*(a-1));
  c=d[a];d[a]=d[b];d[b]=c;
 }
};
var el=document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnails'),l=el.length;
var n=[];while(l--){n[l]=l};
fys(n)
```

n now contains the array with the random indexes and you use

`el[n[0]]` to call the first random element.

Comment: What prevents this from choosing the same item all 3 times, resulting in only one item being moved?

Comment: This also has an extremely small chance that `el[el.length]` will be selected, which is undefined.

Comment: The best way to explain something to people is always to use the shortest variables names possible, so people clearly understand what a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h and i variables are set too, since those are easy to remember. **FALSE!** Use proper variable names when you're posting examples. Not everyone that's reading the answer is at ease with JavaScript yet.

Comment: the Fisher-Yates shuffle would be to long. the only 2 vars you need to read are el & n ... el contains the element collection with the class thumbnails, n contains an array with the shuffled indexes of the el.pls...

Answer (score 0):

Simple for one element do this:

```
var items = $('.item').length;
var currentItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * (items + 1));
$('.item').eq(currentItem).doSomething();
```

For some elements:

```
var number = 10;
for(i=0; i <= number; i++) {
    $('.item').eq(randomElement('.item')).doSomething();
}

function randomElement(el){
    var items = $(el).length;
    var currentItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * (items + 1));
    return currentItem;
}
```